# How to Write a Temporary 'Goodbye"

Tags: fiction, novel, editing

I'm working on my first novel, and my main character is going on a 'no contact' vacation where she doesn't communicate with anyone in her life. I'm struggling to figure out how to write it even though it's only temporary (one month). This is what I have so far;

> "Are you sure?"
>
> "Yes," I say to my obnoxiously loving husband.
>
> Dyllan's used to me pushing him away at this point, yet he still begs to drive me to the airport every year. I take a one-month vacation by myself to Rhode Island every year to motivate myself to write. I go alone and cut off all communication with my spouse, friends, and family. It's a necessary part of my year to develop ideas for novels. I often get stressed, putting pressure on myself to create the best ideas possible, and take it out on my husband.
>
> "Sophie always drives you. I can go in late today and say my car got snowed in or something."
>
> "Dyllan, stop. You're not going in late for work to take me to the airport. It's not that big of a deal, baby. You'll see me in a month," I say, moments before the front door slams open, revealing my best friend of nine years.
> Sophie.
>
> Sophie and I have always been extremely close. It's harder staying away from her for a month than any other person I know. She's ditzy, loud, and beyond gorgeous. But, the girl hates my husband.
>
> "Dyllan," Sophie says with an unamused look. This forces my husband to gaze away from me and onto the obnoxiously honest individual in the door frame. "You haven't left for work yet?"
>
> "No, Sophia, but your sudden visit gives me a reason to." Dyllan looks at me, kisses my temple, and says his goodbyes.

Comment: Your narrator should be a character first. They narrate their *own* thoughts. They (usually) don't know the reader is there, and they don't explain things they already know…. Sophie and Dyllan are *in the room* and both competing for attention. This is a good time to *show* how these characters are towards each other... Narrator should be occupied with their current task (packing Chekov's gun, which will be important later).

Comment: The text that you pasted has nothing to do with saying goodbye. It would help if you could address at least the following points in your question: What have you tried? Why were you not satisfied with your attempts?

Comment: There isn't any goodbye because I'm not sure how to write it without being dramatic or unbelievable. I've never written anything this big before so in the text I just put, "He said his goodbyes." I didn't know how to write the goodbye.

Answer (score 1):

## Not all goodbyes need to say 'goodbye'.

The first step is to decide what each character stands to gain and lose from the departure. For instance, in the example you give, the MC:

- gains time to work on her project
- gains personal time to recharge
- gains distance from her current situation
- gains the excitement of a new adventure
- loses the support of her husband and friends
- loses money
- loses the comfort of her known environment

The second step is decide for each character what is the net balance of gains and losses, or what is the theme. For instance, for the MC the net is a gain, and the theme is to get personal time from a relationship that she feels strained. For the husband the net is a loss as he loses the companionship of his wife. You can put these nets in a table.

In the example I am constructing, the MC is thus happy to go, while the husband is adverse to the departure. At this point, you can construct your scene by showing us these contrasting attitudes. The MC may be very keen on leaving quickly, she may speak with short sentences, be focused on not reveal too much of her plans, make sure she took everything, but skips over scheduling calls; the husband may be more clingy, he may insist on taking her to the airport, carrying the luggage, putting some mementos while MC is not looking, trying to make MC agree on a set time to talk while she's away.

If both had to gain from the departure, they may be more proactive in getting to the airport, more cheerful about the event, and the scene may be shorter.

All in all, there is no need to say 'goodbye'. The true goodbye is in the actions, in the attitude, in talking about irrelevant things only to delay MC a bit more, or not talking at all, to make sure she leaves quickly. In this light, a departure scene is the moment to show the inner workings of a relationship as it comes close to a (temporary perhaps) turning point.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it "off the grid" for a month.

Or a "meditation retreat", which is what it sounds like.

Or something new and more specific: A creative retreat.

Or creative meditation retreat.

I'd have somebody new, a friend or coworker that doesn't quite get it, create a minor conflict that gives an excuse to explain it.

> I called Sarah. "Hey Sarah, I'm going on a retreat for a month in the
> Alps, I just wanted to give you a heads up."
>
> "Okay,well I'll text you if I have any problems."
>
> "You can't. I'll be off the grid, entirely, no contact. I always do
> this before I start a new book."
>
> She sounded upset. "None at all?"
>
> "Zip. Nada. Zero. But I'm okay, I just can't have any distractions. No
> phone, no email, no nothing."
>
> "But what if we hit a snag that needs you?"
>
> "Well, if it is writing, tell them the truth, I'm away and off the grid. Anything business related, I trust you to make reasonable decisions."

Answer (score 0):

### The Goodbye Doesn't Matter

Exactly how the POV character says goodbye - with a hug, or a kiss, or with tears, or whatever - doesn't matter. It doesn't really show us anything meaningful about the character.

### The Conflict DOES Matter

You have a throw-away line about how Dyllan and Sophia are enemies, and then the two start sniping at each other.

Dig into this. Amplify it. Expand it.

The conflict is the source of tension in the scene, and how your POV character responds to this conflict gives the reader very meaningful insight into who they are.

### Turning up the Conflict

What if Sophia was supposed to drive the POV character, but her car broke down a block from the house? Now we have more conflict. Sophia still wants to drive, but she'd have to take Dyllan's car. Dyllan's not having it. He points out how she's consistently unreliable, and how if she took care of her car, it would take care of her.

Etc. Etc.

Now the POV character has to take a side. That's probably going to anger one of the two. Who does she pick? Why?

Your scene will be stronger if you concentrate on the stakes - and if you turn those stakes up by finding more conflict!